# How to deal with theorem vs thm mismatch

Tags: math-mode, alias

I often find that I want to include a LaTeX file that has uses the 
environment `theorem` defined, but my document class has instead defined environment `thm`, so I get errors like `Environment theorem not defined`.

What is the easiest way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add lines like the following to your preamble:

```
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{thm}}{\end{thm}}
\newenvironment{lemma}  {\begin{lem}}{\end{lem}}
```